# Where was the Chancellor's office located in the Senate Office Building?

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith

The great [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/151798/did-anyone-on-coruscant-see-film-the-duel-between-mace-windu-and-chancellor-palp) about whether there were any witnesses to the duel between Darth Sidious and Mace Windu made me thinking about the location of the Chancellor's office...

The Senate Office Building was a dome-shaped office building located close to the Senate Building on Coruscant. Among many offices it also contained the Chancellor's office which, according to [Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Chancellor%27s_office), was located near the top of the building.

[image: Skyline of Coruscant with the dome of the Executive Building in mid-frame]

However, if we take a look at a cutaway taken from *Star Wars: Complete Locations*, we notice that the exterior walls of the office are straight vertical. This shouldn't be possible on the top of a dome-shaped building.

[image: 3D cutaway rendering of a building with vertical sides]

In addition, in the scene from *Revenge of the Sith* where Windu's lightsaber fell down from the office window, the walls appeared to lead almost straight down.

[image: Mace Windu's lightsaber dropping from a great height down the side of a building to lighted buildings below]

Of course, it could be said that the scene was taken from the very end of the lightsaber fall, close to the street level. But in that case, shouldn't we be seeing only the lower floors of the surrounding buildings?

So, was this a movie mistake or was there possibly a straight vertical structure on the other side of the Senate Office Building that we just cannot see? In my opinion, regarding to these observations, the Chancellor's office could not have been located on the top of a dome-shaped building.

Comment: Is that a bedroom in the back part of the Chancellor's office complex?

Comment: @RichS Sure looks like one. Could it be a bed on which someone was killed in his sleep...?

Comment: Thinking of Darth Plagueis? He was in a banking clan, not a chancellor.

Comment: Just quickly thought he might have been killed in the complex. But no, according to Legends, the murder took place at Plagueis' penthouse in the Kaldani Spires building.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO it is possible that the floor plan of the Senate office building may resemble a keyhole.  It may have a cylinder attached to a rectangle or something.

Maybe the flat area in the foreground of the image is not a level piece of ground leading to the low senate building.  Maybe it is the roof of the rectangular section of the Senate building that is thousands of feet high.  Maybe the low dome is not resting on the ground but is on top of a cylinder thousands of feet high.

Thus at least one section of the Senate office building could have windows in a vertical wall thousands of feet high.

I thought that ground level on Coruscant was supposed to be miserable slums and shut off from light by miles high buildings.  But the picture of the Senate building is all in full light and seems to have a flat paved area leading to a large doorway.  So possibly important people are supposed to enter the building there and thus the level is probably not ground level in the slums.

Answer (score 0):

The Republic Executive building was built after Naboo. Since its main window has no view of the Senate dome any of the three compass directions in a 360 degree layout. While the building is a Dome its massive size doesn't mean it's perfectly smooth circular. The building is nearly a kilometer in diameter. So broad curves aren't visible except at distance. The dome up close also has numerous grooves and tiers on its surface to have vertical and horizontal floors for his office layout.[image]